# Which version of web3 shall i be using now?

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs, web3js-v1.x

I found the documentation of **version  1.0.0 which was released on the 6th of August** [here](http://file:///home/parin/Documents/bitsbeat/web3jsV1.0.pdf). I was told that v1 is not stable and very different than earlier versions. But when i check the available versions using command `npm view web3 versions it shows

```
  '1.0.0-beta.55',
  '1.0.0-beta1',
  '1.0.0-beta2',
  '1.2.0',
  '1.2.1',
  '2.0.0-alpha',
```

these many versions.  Can you suggest me which verison shall i go for if i want to follow the [given](http://file:///home/parin/Documents/bitsbeat/web3jsV1.0.pdf) documentation.

And what is the difference in version 0.* and 1.*?

Comment: The links that you added are broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web3 1.2.1 is basically the most stable 1.0.0 version(beta37) and 2.0.0 is slightly improved 1.0.0-beta.55 as you can see in the releases [page](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/releases). It is explained in this medium [post](https://medium.com/@samuel_91690/1-0-release-web3-js-ddd23d3c8f62). You can find the documentation for 1.2.1 and 2.0.0 alpha [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3.html) and [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.0-alpha/web3.html) respectively.